# Updating a mySQL row containing IDs

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a mySQL table that have a column `read_by` which has the rows:

```
-17-6
-11-8-6-62
-6
-6-22-45
-16-77
-31-3-6-24
```

These are IDs of users, Every ID starts with a dash `-`

Now I have changed the user 6 to 136

How to update every row and just change 6 to 136 keeping in mind that there may be IDs like -16, -62, -167... and the ID 6 is in different positions.

Here are the WHERE conditions:

```
WHERE read_by = "-6"
WHERE read_by LIKE "%-6"
WHERE read_by LIKE "-6-%"
WHERE read_by LIKE "%-6-%"



UPDATE messages SET [...] WHERE ...
```

How to change the exact 6 and keep the rest as is?

Thanks.

Comment: Never, ever store data as dash separated items. (Or comma separated etc.) It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: At least don't store lists of items if you actually need to use SQL to query or update individual items in the list. It might be okay to store a list if you always just store and fetch the whole list, not individual items in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to append a dash to the column in order to filter and the remove it after the update:

```
update messages 
set read_by = trim(trailing '-' from replace(concat(read_by, '-'), '-6-', '-136-'))
where concat(read_by, '-') like '%-6-%'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/markdown?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=e7c10c257ca763daad3f21926ffe5bdc).
Results:

```
> | read_by      |
> | :----------- |
> | -17-136      |
> | -11-8-136-62 |
> | -136         |
> | -136-22-45   |
> | -16-77       |
> | -31-3-136-24 |
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to change all "6"s to "136", you can do:

```
update t
    set read_by = trim(both '-' from replace(concat('-', read_by, '-'), '-6-', '-136-'))
    where concat('-', read_by, '-') like '%-6-%';
```

Then, you should think about fixing your id.  Use an auto-incremented number.  Information such as "6" should be stored in a column somewhere.